# Delphi REST Client cookies

Tags: rest, delphi

I am trying to read cookies of a Delphi REST Client Response (TRestResponse) but I can't see how's that possible. There is no straight method (like Cookies or GetCookies) and inside response headers "set-cookie" entries are missing. I searched delphi sources, as well as the whole stackoverflow and I couldn't find any reference. Is it possible to read cookies sent by server?

[headers from Delphi App with REST Client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRlUO.png)

[headers from Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDOj7.png)

Comment: Consider using THTTPClient instead. TRESTClient don't exposes an interface to access cookies.